# Python kivy android barcode scanner

Tags: android, python, kivy, barcode

My app is written in Python using kivy and it should run on android device. I need to read a barcode and use the value in this app therefore I would like to have at the end a single apk with the integration of the barcode reader. I also tried to use an example with SL4A and this run and give me in clipboard the value from scanner but the same code doesn't work outside SL4A.
Is there somewhere an example of code for an application that read a barcode and use that value?
Thank you.

Comment: are you asking how to read a barcode from an image?

Comment: Not exactly. The way used to read the barcode (from image like SL4A or any other way) isn't my trouble. What I'm searching for is how I can integrate in my code (Python and Kivy) the code that read the barcode. For instance: a simple window on mobile with a button for starting the scanner and a label in which I can see the value of the barcode. What happen after the click is not important but should be automatically started.